# Memory content behind C struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Browsing through some old C code, and I came across this snippet. I am thoroughly confused as to what is happening behind the scenes.

I don't have a full understanding of struct pointer usage and operability, and I can't quite understand how the memory is being stored and accessed in the following code.

```
struct x{
int i1;
int i2;
char ch1[8];
char ch2[8];
};

struct y{
long long int f1;
char f2[18];
};

int main(void)
{
struct x * myX;
struct y * myY;
myX = malloc(sizeof(struct x));
myX->i1 = 4096;
myX->i2 = 4096;
strcpy(myX->ch1,"Stephen ");
strcpy(myX->ch2,"Goddard");
myY = (struct y *) myX;
printf("myY->f1 = %d\n", myY->f1);
printf("myY->f2 = %s\n", myY->f2);
}
```

This outputs

```
 myY->f1 = 4096
 myY->f2 = Stephen Goddard
```

After the cast, `i1` is stored into `myY->f1` and both ch1 & ch2 is stored in `myY->f2`. My question is **how?**. What does the memory content look like after the cast?

I know it has to do with the size of the struct and where the pointer is pointing (obviously), but after looking at this code, it has definitely made me realize my lack of understanding pointers.

Thank you

Comment: The first `strcpy` call invoke undefined behavior too, since it overwrite an array element that doesn't exist, namely `ch1[8]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming a 32-bit `int` here. The memory behind `struct x` has 24 bytes, and the layout is as follows:

```
Bit   0000 0000 00111111 11112222
      0123 4567 89012345 67890123
      ----|----|--------|--------
Field  i1   i2     ch1      ch2
```

Here is what happens after the first `strcpy`:

```
      ----|----|--------|--------
Field  i1   i2     ch1      ch2
      ----|----|--------|--------
                Stephen \0
                         ^
                         |
                  Zero terminator
```

Here is what happens after the second `strcpy`:

```
      ----|----|--------|--------
Field  i1   i2     ch1      ch2
      ----|----|--------|--------
                Stephen  Goddard\0
                                 ^
                                 |
                           Zero terminator
```

Note how the terminating zero from the first `strcpy` gets written over to complete the string.

Here is the layout of `struct y`:

```
Bit   00000000 001111111111222222
      01234567 890123456789012345
      --------|------------------
Field     f1            f2
```

When you cast a pointer of `struct x` to `struct y`, you do not copy anything. The layout of `struct y` is aligned with the layout of `struct x` like a cookie cutter, and then the content of combined `x.ch1` and `x.ch2` is taken through the `f2` "window":

```
        --------|------------------
Y Field    f1            f2
X Field  i1 | i2     ch1 |    ch2
        --------|------------------
                 Stephen  Goddard\0
```

As far as printing `4096` goes, that's undefined behavior: you are passing `f1`, which is of type `long long int`, to `printf` in a position of an `int` parameter, so `printf` "reinterprets" the data as an `int`, chopping off the upper half (undefined behavior). The number that you get if you use an appropriate format specifier is `17592186048512`.

Comment: Why is it that f1 only stores 4096 and not 40964096?

Comment: @ElliotM Actually, it stores `17592186048512`. However, your program tells `printf` that it's an `int`, so `%d` chops off the other four bytes.

Answer (score 6):

The memory isn't affected by the cast. The cast just treats one object as though it was of another one of a different type. If you will, think of the code as having a `union { struct x a; struct y b; }`, and then writing to `a` but reading from `b`.

This is undefined behaviour, but it so happens to come out that the various objects overlay each other so you see the observed result.

The first `strcpy(myX->ch1,"Stephen ");` is also undefined behaviour, since the buffer is too small for the string.

Comment: I guess my real question is, after the cast, how does myY->f2 now contain myX->ch1 & ch2?

Comment: @ElliotM: The `f2` subobject of the `y` struct sits at the same memory location as the `ch1` subobject of the `x` struct; the first null terminator is overwritten by the second `strcpy` (note that there's a buffer overrun).

Answer (score 1):

As for the memory, it still holds only the values from the `struct x` that was initially `malloc`ed plus the two pointers `myX` and `myY`, both pointing at `struct x`.

However, it just so happens that `ch1` and `f2` begin at the same relative memory index 8 (and `i1` and `f1` do too, obviously, index 0) and `f2` also overlaps with `ch2`, so you get:

```
                      i1    i2    ch1               ch2
from x's perspective: [int] [int] [char] [char] ... [char] ...
from y's perspective: [long long] [char] [char] ... [char] ...
                      f1          f2
                      0     4     8      9          16
```

This works because a `long long` is as long as two `int`s, namely 8 bytes.